# Python GUI html+css package

Tags: python, html, css

I want create python GUI application. I want use html+css for drawing controls (buttons, comboboxes and other) because I already have source code for them. Ultimately I want have executable file (generated with PyInstaller or with other 'py to exe' packages).
I don't want use packages which represent webserver because I am going to use my application on WinPE which has many of limitations and problems.

What package I can use for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way to do this, but there are multiple GUI packages in Python which have web browser objects (or can be used to make them).

Here's an example from PySide:

https://deptinfo-ensip.univ-poitiers.fr/ENS/pyside-docs/PySide/QtWebKit/

You can also search for examples on tkinter (Pythons standard GUI package), pyqt will be similar to pyside.

pygtk also has possibilities.

You can use these packages to build a primitive (or not if you put a lot of time into it) browser which you pipe your templates into based on user input.

Answer (score 0):

How about TideSDK? http://www.tidesdk.org/

Supports Python, PHP, and Ruby and is pretty popular choice.